# Preserving XML formatting in HttpWebResponse in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

I have a .NET project which posts data to foreign web server in the form of a SOAP object via HTTP POST. This is done using a `HttpWebRequest` object. I get a response from the web server, which I am capturing with an `HttpWebResponse` object. This response object is also XML surrounded by a SOAP envelope.

The problem is, when I take the response and output it to the screen with `ToString` it apparently nukes all of the tags and just combines it all into a single string.

How can I output the returned XML from the web server without removing all the XML formatting/tags?

Here is the code I am using:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "Some Headers");

byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
sResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

Comment: Forgive the horrific grammar in the first few sentences, I wrote that really fast :P

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can edit your question :)

Comment: @optionsix: It looks like you have a different problem; you aren't actually serializing/deserializing XML, your code is just outputting the response from the server.  Assuming this is the exact code you use, it seems the server isn't returning XML.

Comment: No, it definitely is returning XML. I went about it a different way, by taking the response stream and putting it into an XmlTextReader. Looping through the reader with reader.Name shows the tags themselves. I'm building a little engine to spit out the nodes like so: while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "whatever") 
            }

Comment: Hi, Sorry to ask a silly question, but what environment are you trying to display the string? ASP.NET? Console? Are the tags eaten if you place a breakpoint after the sResponse line? (I guess not, otherwise you won't be able to load it into an XmlTextReader).I posted the answer assuming you had a formatting problem, then I noticed your issue is that the tags are getting eaten. I'm not deleting my original answer since it is something that you will still find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could format an xml to pretty-printed form as follows:

```
string xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><foo><bar></bar></foo>";
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xml);

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
settings.Indent = true;
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memStream, settings))
{
    document.Save(writer);
}
memStream.Flush();

string formattedXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.ToArray());

// strip UTF-8 BOM if required. Good for display purposes, can leave as such
// for normal processing.
string preAmble = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
if (formattedXml.StartsWith(preAmble)) 
{
    formattedXml = formattedXml.Remove(0, preAmble.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(formattedXml);
}
```

Outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar></bar>
</foo>
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Anash